# Conditional PDF of maximums

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $X=\underset{i=1,...,N}\max(X_i)$ and $Y=\underset{i=1,...,N}\max(Y_i)$, where each pair of random variables $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are correlated with a correlation coefficient $\rho$, and have a joint PDF $f_{X_i,Y_i}\left(x,y\right)$

I am trying to prove an equation in a paper which states that the conditional PDF of $X=\underset{i=1,...,N}\max(X_i)$ given $Y=\underset{i=1,...,N}\max(Y_i)$; i.e., $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ is written in terms of $f_{X_i,Y_i}\left(x,y\right)$ and the marginal PDF $f_{Y_i}(y)$, for the case of i.i.d $X_i$ and also $Y_i$ as follows:

\begin{equation}
f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{X_i,Y_i}\left(x,y\right)}{f_{Y_i}(y)}
\end{equation}

I tried to prove it but I end up having this ratio but multiplied with another one involving the joint CDF of $X_i,Y_i$ and the CDF of $Y_i$,

I would appreciate your support,

Thank you,

Comment: The formula you write implies that $f_{X_i|Y_i}(x|y)=f_{X|Y}(x|y)$. If all $X_i$'s are independent of all $Y_i$'s you would then get $f_{X_i}(x)=f_X(x)$ which is generally not correct.

Comment: Actually your first equation is what I want to prove, as I have each $(X_i,Y_i)$ pair are correlated with a given joint PDF $f_{X_i,Y_i}(x,y)$. I came accross some books of ordered statistics, but trying to find the proof behind it.